# Creating your own authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I a looking to create a user authentication system on my own (using Rails 3) since I do not need all the features that for example authlogic or Device is offering, no matter how great they are. I am going to use the system for handling user authentication as an API that my iPhone app is going to use.

These are my simple requirements.

1. Basic email/password
2. Token based authentication from the iPhone app.

Could someone point out a great guide or blog post discussing this or simular so that I can get started and make sure I do not miss vital security issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Railscast #250: [Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch). Should cover what you need it to.

Comment: Looking good! Is there a way to use a token instead of email/password when signing in/requesting resources (API)?